# Is there any way to always show the noOptionText in material ui Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to show the `noOptionsText` even though there are results from the search in material UI autocomplete. I want it to be in the bottom of the suggestions just like in the picture below:

[image: noOptionsText demonstrated as I would like to have it]